# Is it possible to create an in-memory File object in Java?

Tags: java

One of the optimization projects I'm working on right now makes extensive use of [EPANet](https://github.com/Baseform/Baseform-Epanet-Java-Library). We make repeated calls to two simulation methods in EPANet to understand how water flows through a water distribution network.

[HydraulicSim](https://github.com/Baseform/Baseform-Epanet-Java-Library/blob/master/src/org/addition/epanet/hydraulic/HydraulicSim.java) is one of the classes we make use of. See the overloaded `simulate` methods:

```
public void simulate(File hyd) throws ENException {
    ...
}

public void simulate(OutputStream out) throws ENException, IOException {
    ...
}

public void simulate(DataOutput out) throws ENException, IOException {
    ...
}
```

The other class we use is [QualitySim](https://github.com/Baseform/Baseform-Epanet-Java-Library/blob/master/src/org/addition/epanet/quality/QualitySim.java). Here, we also use the overloaded `simulate` methods:

```
public void simulate(File hydFile, File qualFile) throws IOException, ENException {
    ...
}

void simulate(File hydFile, OutputStream out) throws IOException, ENException {
    ...
}
```

Here's what we're currently doing:

1. Create two `File` objects, `hydFile` and `qualFile`.
2. Call `HydraulicSim.simulate` on `hydFile`.
3. Call `QualitySim.simulate` on `hydFile` and `qualFile`.
4. Delete the files.

The problem is that we have to do this *a lot* of times. For a large problem, we can do this hundreds of thousands or even millions of times. You can imagine the slowdown repeatedly creating/writing/deleting these files causes.

So my question is this: Is it possible for me to create these files so that they reside only in memory and never touch the disk? Each file is very small (I'm talking a few hundred bytes), so throwing them into memory won't be a problem; I just need to figure out how. I searched around and didn't really find much, save for [MappedByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html), but I'm not sure how, or if it's even possible, to create a `File` from that class.

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: It might be worth it to submit an issue to the EPANet team. The simulate methods all simply use the File objects to obtain input and output streams. If they provided a `QualitySim.simulate` method that took the streams as params (which they do for the output stream but not the input stream) you could bypass the FS. Or just fork it and do it yourself.

Comment: You can use ByteArrayOutputStream and ByteArrayInputStream, but you must pre-allocate the byte array to be large enough.

Comment: Do you have to use files? Since you already have some functions that use Streams you could use ByteArrayOutputStream and ByteArrayInputStream instead.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings The QualitySim class doesn't provide a method that accepts a stream for the input parameter (hydFile).

Comment: @MikeB yeah I saw that, but the change would be trivial to implement as you already mentioned. So I would just add the method an make a pull request for them to include it.

Comment: Yeah, I think ultimately, this may be the way to go. It should be a pretty simple fix. I'll discuss these options with my boss.

Comment: @MikeB, I just spent some time modifying EPANet, and that was indeed the way to go! The changes were pretty simple to make. I [opened an issue](https://github.com/Baseform/Baseform-Epanet-Java-Library/issues/2), so I'll see about submitting a pull request as a follow-up.

Comment: @MikeB, can you throw your post into a separate answer so that I can mark it as the answer I used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be worth it to submit an issue to the EPANet team. The simulate methods all simply use the File objects to obtain input and output streams. If they provided a `QualitySim.simulate` method that took the streams as params (which they do for the output stream but not the input stream) you could bypass the FS. Or just fork it and do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! The issue and pull request are now live at https://github.com/Baseform/Baseform-Epanet-Java-Library/issues/2

Answer (score 7):

The most straightforward solution is to mount ramdisk and store file here. Then you do not need to touch your code and file access will be lightning fast :-)

**Linux**

```
# mkfs -q /dev/ram1 8192
# mkdir -p /ramcache
# mount /dev/ram1 /ramcache
```

**MacOS**

1. http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/23/create-a-ram-disk-in-mac-os-x/

**Windows**

1. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257405
2. http://www.softperfect.com/products/ramdisk/

Comment: I love this option, but two of the devs use Windows, and my main dev machine is a Mac (OSX 10.8.x). Is there an equivalent option for MS and Apple devs?

Comment: I googled http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/23/create-a-ram-disk-in-mac-os-x/ and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257405

Comment: It looks like the OSX option could be viable, but the Windows option is for Windows 2000. Ideally, I'd love a solution that is platform-agnostic.

Comment: Another: http://www.softperfect.com/products/ramdisk/. It is just setup script that differs on each platform.

Answer (score 4):

you can use **[Memory mapped file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file)**. Java provides APIs in `FileChannel` Class e.g.

```
channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, start, PAGE_SIZE)

public abstract MappedByteBuffer map(FileChannel.MapMode mode,
                   long position,
                   long size)
                              throws IOException
```

Java provides only 32 bit pointer to manipulate the `MappedByteBuffer` but you can use slicing to map more than 2GB of file e.g.

```
private void memoryMapFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        FileChannel channel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
        List<MappedByteBuffer> buffers = new ArrayList<MappedByteBuffer>();
        long size = channel.size();
        long start = 0;
        int index = 0;
        for (index = 0; start + PAGE_SIZE <= size; index++) {       
            buffers.add(index, channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, start, PAGE_SIZE));
            start = (index+1)*PAGE_SIZE;
        }
        if(start+PAGE_SIZE > size){
            buffers.add(index, channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, start, PAGE_SIZE));
        }
    }
```

Comment: And how do you get the methods that accept a File object and construct the streams by themselves to use this file? Does it suffice to just call `memoryMapFile(File file)` before invoking the other function?

Comment: Thanks for this. Your example more clearly shows how to use `MappedByteBuffer`. I guess the problem is still that I've gotta pass a `File` object into these methods, though. I think modifying the EPANet code is ultimately what I need to do.

Answer (score 2):

It might be overkill but Java 7 provides a way to create custom file systems:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/filesystemprovider.html

You can use this to create your own in memory file system that is backed by a Map or byte[]s.  However, it appears that the FileSystem uses the new `Path` object, not a `File` (although there are methods to convert to/from file)

Might be overkill for what you are trying to do though.