# SSH Authentication Fail : Java JSCH

Tags: java, git, ssh, jsch

My user would need to validate his Private Key against his Git Repository . It is similar to "Test Connection" button in any DB Client tool.

I am using JSCH to do this validation in Java (i just need to connect using SSH and tell that connection is successful). Below is my Java code

```
public class SSHConnect {


    private String filePath = "c:\\me\\ssh-keys\\config_31_jan";


    public static void main(String... args) {
         new SSHConnect().invoke();
    }

    public void invoke () {
        JSch jSch = new JSch();
        try {

            jSch.addIdentity(filePath);
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            Session session = jSch.getSession("MY_USER_NAME","github.my_company.com",22) ;
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I get the below exception.

```
c:\me\ssh-keys\config_31_jan
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at com.pcfdev.main.SSHConnect.invoke(SSHConnect.java:32)
    at com.pcfdev.main.SSHConnect.main(SSHConnect.java:18)
```

I referred all other SO Forums and the solution given was to add the Public key in the corresponding server. I did that and **am able to succesfully Authenticate using my SSH Command** (as mentioned below). But i couldn't achieve the same using JSCH. Please help

```
WGC1008Q5B8H2 MINGW64 /c/me/ssh-keys
$ ssh -i config_31_jan -T git@github.my_company.com
Hi ARUNK2/spring-cloudconfig! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 jSch.getSession("MY_USER_NAME","github.my_company.com",22) ;
```

This should be instead:

```
 jSch.getSession("git","github.my_company.com",22) ;
```

You want to open an ssh connection as git, not as you.
Then your public key on the server side will authenticate you as you.

Comment: One more question. Is there a way to add privateKey as a string directly ? rather mentioning it as `FilePath`

Comment: Adding the *private* directly hard-coded in the code would be a bad practice, so I hope not.

Comment: I am writing a App that will accept `Private-Key` from a  `HTML texbox` and then validate against `git` and upon successful validation given him back some `auto-configruations` JSON File. So i will have to inject the value from the textbox to my `JSCH` code

Comment: Can you inject it in a temporary file, whose path you would then inject or use in your code?

Comment: @Arun Or at least, if you don't have write access to the user TEMP folder, write it in memory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22307964/6309 or in a byte stream: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17595282/6309

Comment: JSCH had another method of `addIdentity` which accepted privateKey as Bytes `jSch.addIdentity("privateKey",privateKeyBytes,null,null);`